# tensorflow memory MNIST tutorial

Tags: python, memory, tensorflow, gpu, mnist

I'm trying to complete MNIST tutorial from [tensorflow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/mnist/pros/index.html)
I have 2gb geforce 760gtx and run out of memory every time.
I have tried to reduce batch size in those lines of code at the end of script:

```
for i in range(20000):
batch = mnist.train.next_batch(5)
if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
```

But it always try to use the same amount of ram. Im new to tensorflow and I want to ask, where can I reduce memory usage in this example, or is there a code to push it through CPU?

Full code:

```
# Load mnist data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

# Start TensorFlow InteractiveSession
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Build a Softmax Regression Model

# 1. Placeholders
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

# 2. Variables
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# 3. Predicted Class and Loss Function
y = tf.matmul(x,W) + b
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y, y_))

# Train the Model
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
for i in range(1000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1]})

# Evaluate the Model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print(accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels}))

# Build a Multilayer Convolutional Network
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

# Convolutional and Pooling
def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')

# First Convolutional Layer
W_conv1 = weight_variable([5,5,1,32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,28,28,1])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# Second Convolutional Layer
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5,5,32,64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# Densely Connected Layer
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7*7*64,1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1,7*7*64])
h_fc1  = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# Dropout
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# Readout Layer
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024,10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

# Train and Evaluate the Model
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
for i in range(20000):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(5)
    if i%100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Comment: You can find an already decoded version of the MNIST dataset here: http://mnist-decoded.000webhostapp.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I expect the problem to happen not in the training loop, but in the final accuracy evaluation where all the test set is passed in a single batch of 10000 images:

```
print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(
    feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

On GPUs with 2 GB or less this is enough to use up all the available memory. I had the same issue with my GTX 965M.

The solution is to use batches for the evaluation too. You need to compute the total number of batches and accumulate the total accuracy. In code:

```
# evaluate in batches to avoid out-of-memory issues
n_batches = mnist.test.images.shape[0] // 50
cumulative_accuracy = 0.0
for index in range(n_batches):
    batch = mnist.test.next_batch(50)
    cumulative_accuracy += accuracy.eval(
        feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
print("test accuracy {}".format(cumulative_accuracy / n_batches))
```